# Boto3 script to delete all images which are untagged

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-ecr

I want to delete all ecr  images which are untagged

```
import boto3
import pprint

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)


pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
client = boto3.client('ecr', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.describe_repositories(repositoryNames=['localstack-centos'])
#print(response)

""" response1 = client.describe_images(
    repositoryName='localstack-centos',
    #maxResults=2,
    imageIds=[
        {

            'imageTag': 'untagged'
        },
    ],


) """

#print(response1)


response2 = client.list_images(

    repositoryName='localstack-centos',

    maxResults=123,
    filter={
        'tagStatus': 'UNTAGGED'
    }
)

print(response2)
pp.pprint(response2)  

response = client.batch_delete_image(
    registryId='string',
    repositoryName='localstack-centos',
    imageIds=[
        {

            'imageTag': 'untagged'
        },
    ]
)
```

I am able to list all ecr images but not able to delete "untagged" images 
if I replace 'untagged' with latest , that image gets deleted 
how would I refer all untagged images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `imageDigest` to delete an image. Collect the `imageDigest` of the images that you want to delete first, and delete it.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecr')

response = client.list_images(repositoryName='localstack-centos')
untaggedImageList = [image for image in response['imageIds'] if image['imageTag'] == 'untagged']
response2 = client.batch_delete_image(repositoryName='localstack-centos', imageIds=untaggedImageList)

print(response2)
```